# Compute confidence interval for slope

Tags: r, ggplot2, statistics, linear-regression, confidence-interval

I have data collected from two different treatments like this:

```
treat1      treat2
0.007279334 0.004338816
0.017659183 0.011468616
0.012810679 0.008206441
0.018230504 0.011470191
0.052934223 0.036175716
0.017752909 0.011163054
```

and plotted it using ggplot2:

```
p6 = qplot(data=example,x=treat1,y=treat2,color=size,shape=region) 
p6+geom_point(size=2)+
  scale_y_continuous(limits=c(0,0.08))+
  scale_x_continuous(limits=c(0,0.08))
  geom_abline(linetype = 2,color = "grey",intercept=0, slope=1)
```

Attached[image: Example-Plot]

Now I want to see the data-points that fall beyond the 10% error-rate i.e. those are beyond 10% from the slope. Am I correct logically? Basically, if treatments would have had same effect then data-points should have fallen on the slope but they do not in this example. So, I just want to know which data-points are beyond the 10% error-rate.

Bade

Comment: Would passing `slope=0.9` instead of `slope=1` meet your requirements for detecting if points are at least 10% from the indicated line?

Comment: I don't think so and maybe I need to rephrase my question - How do I determine data-points that statistically "different" or "far-away"? Does that make sense?

Comment: If you're asking about statistical tests, I think stats.stackexchange.com is a better place to ask.

Comment: Agreed with previous comments, you should go to stats.stackexchange.com. Anyway, what you are looking for is a t-test, [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Student%27s_t-test), [R implementation](http://www.statmethods.net/stats/ttest.html)